If I want to approach partial differential equations, which book should I read?
I'm looking for an introductory book about PDE to approach this topic and learn about theory and resolution.

Welcome to Math StackExchange. This is your first question and it doesn't fit the Math StackExchange's guideline. It lacks context - why are you interested in finding such a book, what are your background, and effort - have you tried searching on the Internet (including this site) and reading book reviews? Please improve your question. This reference might be useful.

See this
